# Error with converting java object to XML in REST

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, rest

I am doing restful webservice .In this I am getting an xml as post into my service.I just wanted to see whether when i post a xml as string into the service, its creates the xml as such or not.

But when i created rest client and tried to print it, the full xml is not getting created.

The service class is given below:

```
@POST
@Path("/authent")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response getauth(Auth auth)
{

return Response.status(200).entity(auth).build();

}
```

The Auth class which produces xml from java object is given below:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Auth")

public class Auth {

    private Double Ver;


    private String Txn;

    private String UID;

    public Double getVer() {
        return Ver;
    }

    public void setVer(Double ver) {
        this.Ver = ver;
    }

    public String getTxn() {
        return Txn;
    }

    public void setTxn(String txn) {
        this.Txn = txn;
    }

    public String getUID() {
        return UID;
    }

    public void setUID(String uID) {
        this.UID = uID;
    }

}
```

The following is my client code:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class RestClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Client client = Client.create();  
         WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8082/AuthService/rest/persons/authent"); 

        String ab="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Auth><Ver>1.0</Ver<Txn>AuthDemoClient:STGKSITM01:20140311110619352</Txn><UID>336837947024</UID></Auth>";

        String response = resource.type("application/xml").accept("application/xml").post(String.class,ab);
System.out.println(response);
      } catch (Exception e) {    
              e.printStackTrace();    
      }


}
}
```

`String "ab"` is the full xml which i need to get printed.. but the following is getting printed in the console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Auth><UID>336837947024</UID></Auth>
```

Is there any problem in my Auth class which converts java object into XML? I am using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I needed to give @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) in Auth class